# PowerView Security in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssas, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot, powerview

I have made a PowerView report in which I have shown data for all regions (for instance, East, West, Central). I have created a cube role so that User can only see data for region 'Central'. I have also enabled the EffectiveUserName" property in Excel Services in SharePoint.

When User opens the PowerView report, he is able to see all the regions. Can I secure my PowerView report? If yes, then what steps would I need to take?

Comment: This sounds like it isn't really passing the effective user through to the tabular model.  
Can you explain where in SharePoint you created your connection and what options you chose?  Can you confirm that you have kerberos configured correctly?

Comment: Haven't implemented Kerberos. i have checked and PowerView is passing effectiveusername to Tabular model but i was looking for PowerView security in Multi-dimensional cube. After i connect to the cube, i fetch data into the PowerPivot model and create a PowerView on it. I want to secure this powerview made on multidim cube..any idea?

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you have bypassed the security in the your multidimensional model by pulling it into PowerPivot. PowerPivot doesn't have security the way SSAS multidimensional and SSAS tabular do. Since you tagged both Sp2010 and 2013, I'm not sure which you are using.  Sp2013 CU4 allows you to create Power View files on top of a Multidimensional cube.